# How to add a timer to a service?

Tags: android, android-service

I tried adding a timer to OnCreate method, Onstart, and even to an AsyncTask, but the program would crash. Not too sure why! Here is a portion of my code, and in this case I added to OnStart.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");





    }
    private void startTimer()
    {           

        if (found != "Yes Found")
         {


            TimerTask updateProfile = new CustomTimerTask(MyService.this);
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(updateProfile, 0, 60*1000);

         }

    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
        //spool.release();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");

        startTimer();


    }
```

**Timer Code**

```
public class CustomTimerTask extends TimerTask {


            private Context context;
            private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

            // Write Custom Constructor to pass Context
            public CustomTimerTask(Context con) {
                this.context = con;

            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                  //some code here


            }




            }
```

**Error Message**

```
03-17 13:16:35.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7634): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-17 13:16:35.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7634): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.saber.MyService@415c0510 with Intent { cmp=xxxx }: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-17 13:16:35.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7634):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2387)
03-17 13:16:35.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7634):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:127)
03-17 13:16:35.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7634):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1221)
03-17 13:16:35.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7634):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-17 13:16:35.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7634):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-17 13:16:35.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7634):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
03-17 13:16:35.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7634):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-17 13:16:35.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7634):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-17 13:16:35.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7634):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:976)
03-17 13:16:35.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7634):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:743)
03-17 13:16:35.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7634):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-17 13:16:35.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7634): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-17 13:16:35.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7634):     at com.example.saber.MyService.startTimer(MyService.java:67)
03-17 13:16:35.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7634):     at com.example.saber.MyService.onStart(MyService.java:86)
03-17 13:16:35.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7634):     at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:438)
03-17 13:16:35.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7634):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2370)
03-17 13:16:35.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7634):     ... 10 more
```

**Where exactly am I suppose to add the timer ?**

Comment: Strings need to be compared with `!String#equals()` not `!=`. Also, where is `timer` instantianted?

Comment: Make sure that found not null, to check that, use if (!"Yes Found".equals(found))

Comment: I deleted the Found string just to be safe, but same error. I updated the thread and added the timer code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn what a `NullPointerException` is. It means that you are trying to call a method on some object that is `null`.

The stack trace that you listed shows that your `NullPointerException` is on line number 67 of `MyService.java`, in the `startTimer()` method of `MyService`.

When you count lines in your code, I suspect that you will find that line number 67 of `MyService.java` is this line:

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(updateProfile, 0, 60*1000);
```

If that is indeed the line that is causing your exception, it would mean that you are getting a `NullPointerException` because `timer` is `null`. Since you have not shown any code where you initialize the `timer` data member, this is certainly possible.

If line number 67 is not the line that I cite above, then you will need to determine what on line 67 could possibly be `null` -- note that it will be an object that you are calling a method on in that line.

Also, as others have pointed out, you need to learn how to compare objects in Java. `!=` is comparing object *identity*, not object *equality*.